# Unable to change the border radius of <thead>, <tr> elements

Tags: html, css

How can I change the radius of thead and tr element? I want my table to have rounded corners but border-radius is not working for thead and tr but its works for the  element itself. Here is the CSS.

```
table{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:gray;
}
thead {
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:left;
    background:blue;
}
tr{
    border-radius:5px;
}
th,td{
    padding:5px;
}
```

Here is the HTML.

```
   <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Andy</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>40</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody> 
    </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round thead corners in Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450634/round-thead-corners-in-firefox-with-css)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do. You need to add the border radius to the correct corners of the first and last `th` in the row rather than the `thead` like this:

```
th:nth-child(1) {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

th:nth-last-child(1) {
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

Here is a full code snippet:

```css
table{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:gray;
}
tr{
    border-radius:5px;
}
th,td{
    padding:5px;
}
th{
text-align:left;
    background:blue;
    color: #fff;
}
th:nth-child(1) {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

th:nth-last-child(1) {
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
   <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Andy</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>40</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody> 
    </table>
```

Comment: what's the difference between using :firstchild and using nth-child?

Comment: @AndyBrooke thanks for selecting this as the answer. You can indeed use `first-child` if you prefer, indeed that might be better as it is supported to earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

radius needs to be in a th or td so i'd do something like this:

```css
table{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:gray;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

table th {

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:left;
    background:blue;
}

table td{
    border-radius:5px;
}
th,td{
    padding:5px;   
}

td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-style: solid none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
td:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Andy</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>40</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "th" in the css. Then you have to use "border-radius".

```
thead th{
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
text-align:left;
background:blue;
}
```

Add "border-radius" in td too.

```
td{
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px ;
background-color: red;
}
```